# Invalid Type error sending raw transaction using web3 v1.0

Tags: solidity, web3js

I try to send a raw transaction to Ropsten via Infura gateway, I got back the error message

> Invalid Type

Here is my development environment.

- "ethereumjs-tx": "^1.3.7"
- "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.55"

Here is the code:

```
var count = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress, 'pending').then(nonce => {
      console.log('This is the nouce'+ nonce)
      var data = MyContract.methods.transfer(toAddress, 10000, {from: fromAddress});
      var gasPrice = web3.eth.gasPrice;
      var gasLimit = 90000;
  
      var rawTransaction = {
        "from": fromAddress,
        "nonce": web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
        "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
        "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
        "to": toAddress,
        "value": 0,
        "data": data,
        "chainId": 0x03
      };
  
        var privKey = new Buffer('0x...', 'hex');
        var tx = new TX(rawTransaction);
  
        tx.sign(privKey);
        var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
  
      web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {


        if (!err)
            console.log(hash);
        else
            console.log(err);
      });
      console.log(nonce)
    })



"Error: invalid type
    at Object.exports.toBuffer (blob:http://localhost:8089/b24018f3-44b6-48a6-a316-46ad6a2e0477:153167:15)
    at Transaction.setter [as data] (blob:http://localhost:8089/b24018f3-44b6-48a6-a316-46ad6a2e0477:153448:21)
    at blob:http://localhost:8089/b24018f3-44b6-48a6-a316-46ad6a2e0477:153505:65
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.exports.defineProperties (blob:http://localhost:8089/b24018f3-44b6-48a6-a316-46ad6a2e0477:153504:16)
    at new Transaction (blob:http://localhost:8089/b24018f3-44b6-48a6-a316-46ad6a2e0477:152914:15)
    at blob:http://localhost:8089/b24018f3-44b6-48a6-a316-46ad6a2e0477:92532:20
    at tryCallOne (blob:http://localhost:8089/b24018f3-44b6-48a6-a316-46ad6a2e0477:3156:14)
    at blob:http://localhost:8089/b24018f3-44b6-48a6-a316-46ad6a2e0477:3257:17
    at blob:http://localhost:8089/b24018f3-44b6-48a6-a316-46ad6a2e0477:27877:21"
```

New Error message:

```
Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":2,"values":3}, value={"types":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"values":["0x5077174D79d9491AF15Dcf7D1496638D6062A011",10000,{"from":"0xd61794624e9542495A72Cfac7Cc10B4275b8f8E5"}]}, version=4.0.33)
Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":2,"values":3}, value={"types":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"values":["0x5077174D79d9491AF15Dcf7D1496638D6062A011",10000,{"from":"0xd61794624e9542495A72Cfac7Cc10B4275b8f8E5"}]}, version=4.0.33)
```

Comment: can you print full error'

Comment: @AnkushRasgon - I have updated and shared the full error message above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new version of web3 1.x
try using this

```
 to: Contract._address,
  data: Contract.methods.transfer(to, 1000).encodeABI(),
```

Comment: @AnkushRasgon- I've tried that. Now, I got a new error message.  Please see above

Comment: change this   value:'0x0'

Comment: okk wait overall code is okk there is small mistake need time to figure out

Comment: I have figured it out.(Maybe) , I should change this line of code to this MyContract.methods.transfer(toAddress, 10000)..encodeABI(),instead. Removed the from:fromAddress. But, I got new error popped up, it says "The web3.eth.sendRawTransaction is not a function". Maybe, the web3 1.0 doesn't support method anymore?

Comment: renamed to sendSignedTransaction() https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43720/web3-eth-sendrawtransaction-is-not-a-function/43729